# How do I encode/decode between Javascript and ColdFusion?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion form and set a field value by copying it from another form with the Javascript below. (This is actually from a popup input window where you can paste large texts).

```
form1.remark.value = form2.remark.value;
```

After this happens, form1 is submitted for further processing by another `process.cfm` page.

The problem is the `remark.value` contains complex text, including XML, but it is encoded when it arrives at the `process.cfm` page. I'm looking for a way to correctly encode it in the Javascript portion and then decode it at `process.cfm` using ColdFusion code so that I get back the original text, including XML tags.

How is this best accomplished?

Comment: *The problem is the remark.value contains complex text, including XML, but it is encoded when it arrives at the process.cfm page.* So you only want to decode the string in process.cfm?

Comment: @Beginner yes, correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `StringEscapeUtils` class of java like this:

```
<cfset objEscapeUtil = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils")>
<cfset unescapedString = objEscapeUtil.unescapeJavaScript(escapedString)>
```

Comment: Did you mean unescapeJavaScript()?

Comment: @Leigh No. But can use `unescapeEcmascript ()` . There is no method named as unescapeJavaScript() in stringEscapeUtils.

Comment: Must be version related. There is an [unescapeJavaScript()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29) method, but perhaps not in the version bundled with CF. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Leigh I am currently using `CF 9` and `10`. Oh, yes there is `unescapeJavaScript()`.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for checking. I did not test it, but I imagine the "javascript" version, rather than "java" is probably what they want here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use the value of the submitted form field as the value of a JavaScript variable on the next page, then you need to use the built-in (as of ColdFusion 10) function encodeForJavaScript.

```
<cfoutput>var myJSvar = '#encodeForJavaScript(form.myField)#';</cfoutput>
```

This will properly escape the string value of `form.myField`, so that it can be used with JavaScript.

If you're on CF 8 or 9, the OWASP JAR file is loaded into CF (if you're patched up correctly), and you can access the same functions directly by instantiating the correct Java class.

```
<cfset application.xssEncoder = createObject("java", "org.owasp.esapi.esapi").encoder() />

<cfoutput>
var myJSvar = '#application.xssEncoder.encodeForJavaScript(form.myField)#';
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Adrian, I've figured out that I actually don't need to encode when I set the value. Once the form is submitted it will be encoded by the browser according to http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data. Now CF automaticall decodes the payload when I retrieve the value at `process.cfm`. What algorith does CF use to decode? Is it the one specified in http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data (search for the decode section) ?